# HTML: Creating Table Rows

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create a table with different number of columns in each row, but I am having a hard time doing so.

[image: Table]

I am trying this so far, but this results in uneven rows and titles and formats the table all weird.

http://jsfiddle.net/q3M4R/8/

```
<th colspan="2">TITLE </th>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 1</td>
    <td>INFO 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 3</td>
    <td>INFO 4 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 5</td>
    <td>INFO 6 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 7</td>
    <td>INFO 8 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 9</td>
    <td>INFO 10 </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines? What's happening is your table cells are shrinking to fit their content's size. By adding a width and centering the text, you can achieve a better look.

```css
td{width:250px; border: 1px solid black;}
table, th{text-align: center; border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<table>

  <th colspan="2">TITLE </th>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 1</td>
    <td>INFO 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 3</td>
    <td>INFO 4 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 5</td>
    <td>INFO 6 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 7</td>
    <td>INFO 8 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 9</td>
    <td>INFO 10 </td>
  </tr>

  <th colspan="2">TITLE</th>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 1</td>
    <td>INFO 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 3</td>
    <td>INFO 4 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 5</td>
    <td>INFO 6 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 7</td>
    <td>INFO 8 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INFO 9</td>
    <td>INFO 10 </td>
  </tr>
  <table>

  </table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vnx8prek/